# AngularJS $scope.$watch a property ngModel of a select input

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've an AngularJS app with a form generated by a python backend. My problem is to trigger a specific function (listener) when the ngModel of a select input change:

here the rendered html code:

```
<select id="id_vehicle" name="vehicle" ng-model="contract.vehicle" class="ng-valid ng-valid-parse ng-dirty ng-touched">
    <option value="" selected="selected">---------</option>
    <option value="1">Qashqai</option>
    <option value="2">X6</option>
</select>
```

here my Angular code:

```
contract_form_app.controller("mainCtrl", ['$scope', '$http', '$location', '$window', 'djangoForm', function($scope, $http, $location, $window, djangoForm) {

$scope.contract = {
    vehicle: ""
};

function loadVehicleInformation(oldValue, newValue) {
    // This only triggered one time !!!!.
    console.log("Selected vehicle " + $scope.contract.vehicle);
};

$scope.$watch('contract.vehicle', loadVehicleInformation());
```

When I select another option on my select input, my listener function doesn't trigger... why?

ps: When the page has been loaded, the contract object will have a lot of others fields.

Comment: `$scope.$watch('contract.vehicle', loadVehicleInformation);`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I recommend you use `ng-change` instead of a watch on the controller if you're looking to trigger a function when that value changes, that's what `ng-change` is for.

```
<select id="id_vehicle" name="vehicle" ng-change="loadVehicleInformation()" ng-model="contract.vehicle" class="ng-valid ng-valid-parse ng-dirty ng-touched">
    <option value="" selected="selected">---------</option>
    <option value="1">Qashqai</option>
    <option value="2">X6</option>
</select>
```

Comment: You are my hero! I'll accept your answer in 11 minutes :D

Comment: @FabrizioA Lol, glad to be of assistance :)